# Merging points closest to each other in an array of 3 elements each

Tags: c++

I am implementing a simple greedy merging algorithm that merges the two points which are closest to each other and averages their position. After merging two points at indices i and j, I need to replace one of them, say i, by the mean of the two points. Then, copy the last point in the array over the other point, say j, after which I can reduce the array size by 1 with all remaining points being within the new reduced range.
I need to repeat the above step until there are only 3 representative points left, each of which represents a group of merged points. I have written the following code, but I guess it is not able to update the array (pts). I would appreciate if anyone could help me figure out the mistake. Thanks in advance. This is my code:-

```
void merge_point(Point pts[], int &size) {

double a;
int x, y;
Point d;

while(size != 3) {
    double min = get_distance(pts[0],pts[1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < size; j++) {
                get_distance(pts[i], pts[j]);
                if ((a = get_distance(pts[i],pts[j])) <= min) {
                    x = i;
                    y = j;
                }
                a = get_distance(pts[i],pts[j]);
            }
    }

        d = mean_point(pts[x],pts[y]);
        pts[x] = d;
        pts[y] = pts[size-1];
        size = size - 1;
   }
}
```

**When I am entering the input array as :-**

3 8 2

5.7 7.2 2.2

10.83 6.48 2.42

20.577 5.832 2.662

39.0963 5.2488 2.9282

74.283 4.72392 3.22102

141.138 4.25153 3.54312

268.162 3.82638 3.89743

509.507 3.44374 4.28718

968.063 3.09936 4.7159

**My expected output should be:-**

181.974 4.29686 3.57395

968.063 3.09936 4.7159

509.507 3.44374 4.28718

**But, I am getting an output of:**-

4.35 7.6 2.1

968.063 3.09936 4.7159

36.6506 5.8958 2.68145

Comment: Your code looks OK to me (apart from pointlessly calling `get_distance` three times with the same arguments). What makes you believe there's a problem with it? What outcome do you expect, and what do you observe instead?

Comment: The code shown doesn't accept input, nor produce output. To the extent there is a problem, it likely lies in the code not shown. Show a [mcve].

Comment: The code you've posted seems fine, but there are some useless instructions (get_distance called two time with no assigment), also the number of element in the array at the end of the procedure is correct. Maybe something wrong with the code of get_distance and/or mean.

Comment: @SeventhSon84 Yeah, I know but I guess it is not causing the problem I have mentioned.

Comment: I tried your code defining those two functions and it's working fine.

Comment: @SeventhSon84   Could you show me your code and the output, please? Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211950/discussion-between-user13218692-and-seventhson84).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think I find out the problem, you don't update the min distance as soon as you find a new one during the cicle, try this:

```
        cout << "distance between p[" << i << "] and " << "p[" << j << "]" << "is " << get_distance(pts[i], pts[j]) << '\n';

        if ((a = get_distance(pts[i], pts[j])) <= min)
        {
            cout << "current min distance is between point[" << i << "]" << " and point[" << j << "]" << '\n';
            min = a;
            x = i;
            y = j;
        }
```

you've got to add this instruction:

```
min = a;
```

in order to update the min.
Otherwise it will works only for some edge cases.